# Double Negation in R

Tags: r, dataframe, slice

I have a data frame in R:

```
df =

yy     mm  data
2012    1  1000
2012    1  1500 
2013    2  1250
2013    1  1350
```

What I want is to exclude column when yy = 2013 and mm = 1. I tried

```
df[(df$yy != 2013) & (df$mm != 1),]
```

But it does not work.

Comment: It will work if there are rows where neither of conditions are met simultaneously. It may have returning 0 rows in this case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your code to the following:

```r
df[df$yy != 2013 | df$mm != 1,]
```

**Output**

```r
#>      yy    mm  data
#>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1  2012     1  1000
#> 2  2012     1  1500
#> 3  2013     2  1250
```

You can also accomplish this by using `filter` from the `dplyr` package.

```r
library(tibble)
library(dplyr)

df <- tibble::tribble(
   ~yy, ~mm, ~data,
  2012,    1,  1000,
  2012,    1,  1500,
  2013,    2,  1250,
  2013,    1,  1350
  )

df %>% 
  filter(yy != 2013 | mm != 1)

#> # A tibble: 3 x 3
#>      yy    mm  data
#>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1  2012     1  1000
#> 2  2012     1  1500
#> 3  2013     2  1250
```

<sup>Created on 2021-03-17 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Here is a base R option using `subset`

```
subset(
  df,
  !(yy == 2013 & mm == 1)
)
```

which gives

```
    yy mm data
1 2012  1 1000
2 2012  1 1500
3 2013  2 1250
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `fsubset` from `collapse`

```
library(collapse)
fsubset(df, yy != 2013 | mm != 1)
# A tibble: 3 x 3
#     yy    mm  data
#  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#1  2012     1  1000
#2  2012     1  1500
#3  2013     2  1250
```